# Boost BGL BFS Find all unique paths from Source to Target

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I am using Boost BGL C++ and I need the Graph to do a BFS from a Source vertex to a target vertex and return all the unique paths.

Right now, I thought of a way to use a filtered graph to get a subset of the graph containing paths from source to target but i realised that it was basically not filtering since the filtered graph included vertex that are visited but not part of a path from source to target. Is there any way to get this information or a different approach is better?

Code for reference:

```
boost::filtered_graph<DirectedGraph, boost::keep_all, std::function<bool(VertexDescr)>> Graph::getUniquePathsFromSource(VertexDescr source, VertexDescr target, DirectedGraph const & g)
{
    std::vector<double> distances(num_vertices(g));
    std::vector<boost::default_color_type> colormap(num_vertices(g));

    // Run BFS and record all distances from the source node
    breadth_first_search(g, source,
        visitor(make_bfs_visitor(boost::record_distances(distances.data(), boost::on_tree_edge())))
        .color_map(colormap.data())
    );

    for (auto vd : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
        if (colormap.at(vd) == boost::default_color_type{})
            distances.at(vd) = -1;

    distances[source] = -2;

    boost::filtered_graph<DirectedGraph, boost::keep_all, std::function<bool(VertexDescr)>>
        fg(g, {}, [&](VertexDescr vd) { return distances[vd] != -1; });

    // Print edge list
    std::cout << "filtered out-edges:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Source Vertex: " << source << std::endl;

    auto ei = boost::edges(fg);

    typedef boost::property_map<DirectedGraph, boost::edge_weight_t>::type WeightMap;
    WeightMap weights = get(boost::edge_weight, fg);

    for (auto it = ei.first; it != ei.second; ++it)
    {
        if (source != boost::target(*it, g)) {
            std::cout << "Edge Probability " << *it << ": " << get(weights, *it) << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return fg;
}
```

Input (vertex1, vertex2, weight):

```
0 1 0.001
0 2 0.1
0 3 0.001
1 5 0.001
2 3 0.001
3 4 0.1
1 482 0.1
482 635 0.001
4 705 0.1
705 5 0.1
1 1491 0.01
1 1727 0.01
1 1765 0.01
```

Output (For Source = 0, Target = 5):

```
Source Vertex: 0
Edge Probability (0,1): 0.001
Edge Probability (0,2): 0.1
Edge Probability (0,3): 0.001
Edge Probability (1,5): 0.001
Edge Probability (1,482): 0.1
Edge Probability (1,1491): 0.01
Edge Probability (1,1727): 0.01
Edge Probability (1,1765): 0.01
Edge Probability (2,3): 0.001
Edge Probability (3,4): 0.1
Edge Probability (4,705): 0.1
Edge Probability (482,635): 0.001
Edge Probability (705,5): 0.1
```

Expected Output:

```
0->1->5
0->3->4->705->5
0->2->3->4->705->5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't use the BFS algorithm because it uses colormaps to track visited nodes. However, if you want *all* distinct paths you will not want to skip already-visited nodes (because you may skip alternative paths then).

Instead, I'd implement a brute-force breadth-first recursive algorithm that simply visits all adjacent nodes **unless** they're already in the current path.

All state required is the current path.

The idea is explained in more detail here: https://www.quora.com/How-should-I-find-all-distinct-simple-paths-between-2-given-nodes-in-an-undirected-graph

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b4bdb2de4d639a3)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp> // print_graph
using namespace boost;
using Graph = adjacency_list<vecS, listS, directedS, property<vertex_index_t, int>, property<edge_weight_t, double> >;
Graph read_graph();

using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
using Path = std::vector<Vertex>;

template <typename Report>
void all_paths_helper(Vertex from, Vertex to, Graph const& g, Path& path, Report const& callback) {
    path.push_back(from);

    if (from == to) {
        callback(path);
    } else {
        for (auto out : make_iterator_range(out_edges(from, g))) {
            auto v = target(out, g);
            if (path.end() == std::find(path.begin(), path.end(), v)) {
                all_paths_helper(v, to, g, path, callback);
            }
        }
    }

    path.pop_back();
}

template <typename Report>
void all_paths(Vertex from, Vertex to, Graph const& g, Report const& callback) {
    Path state;
    all_paths_helper(from, to, g, state, callback);
}

int main() {
    auto g = read_graph();
    print_graph(g, std::cout);

    auto by_vertex_id = [&](int id) {
        return *find_if(vertices(g), [&](Vertex vd) { return id == get(vertex_index, g, vd); });
    };

    all_paths(by_vertex_id(0), by_vertex_id(5), g, [&](Path const& path) {
            std::cout << "Found path ";
            for (auto v : path)
                std::cout << get(vertex_index, g, v) << " ";
            std::cout << "\n";
        });
    std::cout.flush();
}

// immaterial to the task, reading the graph
Graph read_graph() {
    std::istringstream iss(R"(
        0 1 0.001
        0 2 0.1
        0 3 0.001
        1 5 0.001
        2 3 0.001
        3 4 0.1
        1 482 0.1
        482 635 0.001
        4 705 0.1
        705 5 0.1
        1 1491 0.01
        1 1727 0.01
        1 1765 0.01)");

    Graph g;
    auto vertex = [&,idx=std::map<int,Vertex>{}](int id) mutable {
        auto it = idx.find(id);
        if (it != idx.end())
            return it->second;
        return idx.emplace(id, add_vertex(id, g)).first->second;
    };

    for (std::string line; getline(iss, line);) {
        std::istringstream ls(line);
        int s,t; double w;
        if (ls >> s >> t >> w) {
            add_edge(vertex(s), vertex(t), w, g);
        } else {
            std::cerr << "Skipped invalid line '" << line << "'\n";
        }
    }

    return g;
}
```

Which prints:

```
1 --> 5 482 1491 1727 1765 
0 --> 1 2 3 
2 --> 3 
3 --> 4 
5 --> 
4 --> 705 
482 --> 635 
635 --> 
705 --> 5 
1491 --> 
1727 --> 
1765 --> 
Found path 0 1 5 
Found path 0 2 3 4 705 5 
Found path 0 3 4 705 5
```

Comment: +1 for the answer!

I went ahead with your solution without

`auto by_vertex_id = [&](int id) {
        return *find_if(vertices(g), [&](Vertex vd) { return id == get(vertex_index, g, vd); });
    };
`

From what I understand, this checks if the vertex_index is equal to the vertex descripter?

Comment: You need something to find the descriptor for the source/target vertex, right? If you want to spell it more conventionally (mainly, less lambda): [pure c++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6ab72e2f77e7982) or even [pure c++03](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9f977cb27e000b3). C++ really has come a long way

Comment: Ah I see, I am relatively new to the lambda convention so I'm still learning it as I go. Thanks!