# What should be the return value of a custom function addEdge in a new class based on BGL?

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, api-design, boost-graph

I try to implement a graph class based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/950173/7558038. When adding an edge I return the edge descriptor of the added edge, but if the edge already exists, it shouldn't be added. What shall I return then? Unfortunately, `null_edge()` does not exist (unlike `null_vertex()`). It could be an `std::pair<e_it_t,bool>` with an appropriate edge iterator type `e_it_t`, but how can I get an iterator to the new edge?

Comment: Out of the box: `optional<edge_descriptor>` might be appropriate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use that class that is almost 10 years old. It is obsolete.

[Bundled properties](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html) have come to BGL as long as I know, which is... probably since at least 2010. Nothing there is fundamentally easier than straight boost.

*Another weird property is that somehow only complementary edges can be inserted in that graph. This might be what you want, but it doesn't warrant having the complete class, IMO.*

In fact, having the custom type removes ADL, which makes things more tedious unless you go and add each other operation (like, you know, `out_edges` or `in_edges`, which presumably is what you wanted a bidirectional graph for in the first place; maybe you actually wish to have iterable ranges instead of `pair<iterator, iterator>` which requires you to write old-fashioned for loops).

Now that I've warmed up a bit, lets demonstrate:

### Using The Obsolete Wrapper class

The linked wrapper affords usage like this:

```
struct VertexProperties { int i; };
struct EdgeProperties { double weight; }; 

int main() {
    using MyGraph = Graph<VertexProperties, EdgeProperties>;

    MyGraph g;

    VertexProperties vp;
    vp.i = 42;

    MyGraph::Vertex v1 = g.AddVertex(vp);

    g.properties(v1).i = 23;


    MyGraph::Vertex v2 = g.AddVertex(vp);
    g.properties(v2).i = 67;

    g.AddEdge(v1, v2, EdgeProperties{1.0}, EdgeProperties{0.0});

    for (auto vr = g.getVertices(); vr.first!=vr.second; ++vr.first) {
        auto& vp = g.properties(*vr.first);
        std::cout << "Vertex " << vp.i << "\n";

        for (auto er = g.getAdjacentVertices(*vr.first); er.first!=er.second; ++er.first) {
            auto  s  = *vr.first;
            auto  t = *er.first;
            // erm how to get edge properties now?

            std::cout << "Edge " << g.properties(s).i << " -> " << g.properties(t).i << " (weight?!?)\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
Vertex 23
Edge 23 -> 67 (weight?!?)
Vertex 67
Edge 67 -> 23 (weight?!?)
```

Note I didn't exactly bother to solve the problem of getting the edge-weight (we don't readily get edge descriptors from the interface at all). 
The for loops throw us back in time at least 6 years. And that's not nearly the worst problem. Presumably, you need your graph for something. Let's assume you want minimum cut, or a shortest path. This means you want to invoke an algorithm that requires the edge weight. This would look like so:

```
// let's find a shortest path:
// build the vertex index map
boost::property_map<MyGraph::GraphContainer, vertex_properties_t>::const_type vpmap =
    boost::get(vertex_properties, g.getGraph());
// oops we need the id from it. No problem, it takes only rocket science:
struct GetId {
    int operator()(VertexProperties const& vp) const {
        return vp.i;
    }
};
GetId get_id;
boost::transform_value_property_map<GetId,
    boost::property_map<MyGraph::GraphContainer, vertex_properties_t>::const_type,
    int> id_map 
        = boost::make_transform_value_property_map<int>(get_id, vpmap);

// build the weight map
boost::property_map<MyGraph::GraphContainer, edge_properties_t>::const_type epmap =
    boost::get(edge_properties, g.getGraph());
// oops we need the weight from it. No problem, it takes only rocket science:
struct GetWeight {
    double operator()(EdgeProperties const& ep) const {
        return ep.weight;
    }
};
GetWeight get_weight;
boost::transform_value_property_map<GetWeight, 
    boost::property_map<MyGraph::GraphContainer, edge_properties_t>::const_type,
    double> weight_map 
        = boost::make_transform_value_property_map<double>(get_weight, epmap);

// and now we "simply" use Dijkstra:
MyGraph::vertex_range_t vertices = g.getVertices();
//size_t n_vertices = g.getVertexCount();
MyGraph::Vertex source = *vertices.first;

std::map<MyGraph::Vertex, MyGraph::Vertex> predecessors;
std::map<MyGraph::Vertex, double> distance;

boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(g.getGraph(), source, 
        boost::predecessor_map(boost::make_assoc_property_map(predecessors))
        .distance_map(boost::make_assoc_property_map(distance))
        .weight_map(weight_map)
        .vertex_index_map(id_map));
```

This is not my idea of usability. Just to show it all compiles and runs:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb72ba392c3b4906)</kbd>**

### Replace The Wrapper In 2 Lines Of C++11

Let's replace the whole Graph class template in modern BGL style:

```
template <typename VertexProperties, typename EdgeProperties>
using Graph = adjacency_list<setS, listS, bidirectionalS, VertexProperties, EdgeProperties>;
```

Really. That is a solid replacement, I'll demonstrate it right away.

> In fact, let's **not** do `using namespace boost;` because it pollutes our namespace with all manner of names we might find really useful (like, you know `source` or `num_vertices`) and invites ambiguous symbols:
>
> ```
> template <typename VertexProperties, typename EdgeProperties>
> using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS, VertexProperties, EdgeProperties>;
> ```

### The Same Use-Cases - creation and dijkstra

They are still as simple, or in fact simpler. The full code goes down from 249 lines of code to just 57:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8f861c8d78d99e5)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

namespace MyLib {
    template <typename VertexProperties, typename EdgeProperties>
    using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS, VertexProperties, EdgeProperties>;
}

#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct VertexProperties { int i; };
struct EdgeProperties { double weight; };

int main() {
    using boost::make_iterator_range;
    using MyGraph = MyLib::Graph<VertexProperties, EdgeProperties>;

    MyGraph g;

    auto v1 = add_vertex({42}, g);
    auto v2 = add_vertex({42}, g);
    g[v1].i = 23;
    g[v2].i = 67;

    add_edge(v1, v2, EdgeProperties{ 1.0 }, g);
    add_edge(v2, v1, EdgeProperties{ 0.0 }, g);

    for (auto v : make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
        std::cout << "Vertex " << g[v].i << "\n";
    }

    for (auto e : make_iterator_range(boost::edges(g))) {
        auto s = source(e, g);
        auto t = target(e, g);

        std::cout << "Edge " << g[s].i << " -> " << g[t].i << " (weight = " << g[e].weight << ")\n";
    }

    // let's find a shortest path:
    auto id_map = get(&VertexProperties::i, g);
    auto weight_map = get(&EdgeProperties::weight, g);

    auto source = *vertices(g).first;

    using Vertex = MyGraph::vertex_descriptor;
    std::map<Vertex, Vertex> predecessors;
    std::map<Vertex, double> distance;
    std::map<Vertex, boost::default_color_type> colors;

    boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(
            g, source,
            boost::vertex_color_map(boost::make_assoc_property_map(colors))
            .predecessor_map(boost::make_assoc_property_map(predecessors))
            .distance_map(boost::make_assoc_property_map(distance))
            .weight_map(weight_map)
            .vertex_index_map(id_map));
}
```

I'd say

- that is superior.
- it's just as elegant despite not relying on `using namespace boost` (ADL is the key here)
- and we actually printed the edge weight!

### And It Can Be Cleaner Still

If you switch to a vertex container selector that has implicit vertex index (like `vecS`):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e6eb0fd64078018)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

namespace MyLib {
    template <typename VertexProperties, typename EdgeProperties>
    using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, VertexProperties, EdgeProperties>;
}

#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct VertexProperties { int i; };
struct EdgeProperties { double weight; };

int main() {
    using boost::make_iterator_range;
    using MyGraph = MyLib::Graph<VertexProperties, EdgeProperties>;

    MyGraph g;

    add_vertex({23}, g);
    add_vertex({67}, g);

    add_edge(0, 1, EdgeProperties{ 1.0 }, g);
    add_edge(1, 0, EdgeProperties{ 0.0 }, g);

    for (auto v : make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
        std::cout << "Vertex " << g[v].i << "\n";
    }

    for (auto e : make_iterator_range(boost::edges(g))) {
        auto s = source(e, g);
        auto t = target(e, g);

        std::cout << "Edge " << g[s].i << " -> " << g[t].i << " (weight = " << g[e].weight << ")\n";
    }

    // let's find a shortest path:
    std::vector<size_t> predecessors(num_vertices(g));
    std::vector<double> distance(num_vertices(g));

    boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, *vertices(g).first,
            boost::predecessor_map(predecessors.data()).distance_map(distance.data())
            .weight_map(get(&EdgeProperties::weight, g)));
}
```

Output:

```
Vertex 23
Vertex 67
Edge 23 -> 67 (weight = 1)
Edge 67 -> 23 (weight = 0)
```

### WAIT - Don't Forget About The Question!

I won't! I think the above shows the problem was [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

If you hadn't had the handicap of custom class wrapping, detecting duplicate edges was a given (see [if add_vertex in BGL checks for the existence of the vertex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713682/if-add-vertex-in-bgl-checks-for-the-existence-of-the-vertex/45735347#45735347) for background):

```
struct { size_t from, to; double weight; } edge_data[] = {
    {0, 1, 1.0}, 
    {1, 0, 0.0}, 
    {0, 1, 99.999} // oops, a duplicate
};
for(auto request : edge_data) {
    auto addition = add_edge(request.from, request.to, { request.weight }, g);
    if (!addition.second) {
        auto& weight = g[addition.first].weight;
        std::cout << "Edge already existed, changing weight from " << weight << " to " << request.weight << "\n";
        weight = request.weight;
    }
}
```

This will print **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf9ca5d9de5cff5d)</kbd>**:

```
Edge already existed, changing weight from 1 to 99.999
```

If you prefer you can of course write things more expressively:

```
Graph::edge_descriptor e;
bool inserted;
boost::tie(e, inserted) = add_edge(request.from, request.to, { request.weight }, g);
```

Or, with some c++17 flair:

```
auto [e, inserted] = add_edge(request.from, request.to, { request.weight }, g);
```

#### More From Here

Also, in all likelihood you need to do uniqueness checks on the vertices too, so you end up with graph creation code like you can see in this answer: [Boost BGL BFS Find all unique paths from Source to Target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966933/boost-bgl-bfs-find-all-unique-paths-from-source-to-target/46985434#46985434)

```
Graph read_graph() {
    std::istringstream iss(R"(
        0 1 0.001
        0 2 0.1
        0 3 0.001
        1 5 0.001
        2 3 0.001
        3 4 0.1
        1 482 0.1
        482 635 0.001
        4 705 0.1
        705 5 0.1
        1 1491 0.01
        1 1727 0.01
        1 1765 0.01)");

    Graph g;
    std::map<int,Vertex> idx; // temporary lookup of existing vertices

    auto vertex = [&](int id) mutable {
        auto it = idx.find(id);
        if (it != idx.end())
            return it->second;
        return idx.emplace(id, add_vertex(id, g)).first->second;
    };

    for (std::string line; getline(iss, line);) {
        std::istringstream ls(line);
        int s,t; double w;
        if (ls >> s >> t >> w) {
            add_edge(vertex(s), vertex(t), w, g);
        } else {
            std::cerr << "Skipped invalid line '" << line << "'\n";
        }
    }

    return g;
}
```

Other examples show how you can insert both `a -> b` and `b -> a` while maintaining a mapping between the forward and back edges: [Accessing specific edges in boost::graph with integer index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45937710/accessing-specific-edges-in-boostgraph-with-integer-index)

### Summary

Coming full circle, I recommend getting acquainted with the newer, more elegant Boost Graph features. In the end, it's perfectly normal to encapsulate your graph, and you might end up with an even more polished interface.

Comment: The first two code samples hit a bug in Boost Graph where `dijkstra_shortest_paths` doesn't use the custom color-map as it should. This problem has [been reported in 2010](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Boost-Graph-Library-Dijkstra-Shortest-Path-ignores-color-map-in-named-parameters-td2650984.html) and [supposedly fixed earlier in 1.33.0](http://boost-users.boost.narkive.com/lkDGhFxk/graph-dijkstra-shortest-paths-color-map) but it has crept up again. It's not relevant to this answer, I'll see whether I can report it soonish.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is worth a new question, but your (great, thanks!) answer makes me ask: can you recommend any ordered way to learn BGL? The official docs are not quite suitable for this IMO.

Comment: I used stackoverflow... I must say answering does help get acquainted with the nooks, crannies, quirks and warts. And after a while you get a knack for finding the local optimum that allows both power and readability. It's a journey, but if you have time...

Comment: And if you can answer [tag:boost-graph] questions faster than @sehe

Comment: @Rerito I can assure you that in the [tag:boost] tag you don't have to be in a hurry to be the first to answer. Especially with [tag:boost-graph] you can easily spare a few days. Also, don't get the impression I "ace" these answers in no time: I've [documented for a while](https://www.liveedu.tv/sehe/projects/) how I frequently spend hours trying to answer particular questions.